# Web to lead form

Tags: web2lead

Do we have provision how many "web to lead" forms have been created in my organisation and by whom, when was the form created with list of fields being used.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Where have you started?

Comment: My customer need how many web to lead forms we have created and how to know that? when and by whom the form was created..

Answer (score 2):

No. The web-to-lead form generator just creates some HTML code. There's no "tracking" behind this at all. Since it is just HTML code, a developer with sufficient knowledge of your org could generate the code for an entirely new web-to-lead form by hand.

Comment: If my customer need how many active forms are there and on which site the forms are being used, I believe we Dnt have an answer.

Comment: @PragRK That's exactly right. There's no way to know how many of these forms are floating about. That's why many clients prefer to use the API to capture leads (e.g. force.com site or back-end API calls) so they have more control over the process.